# how can i render form from other controller using link_to in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-5

Hi have project scaffold and that had project list. i have created stage scaffold with some field. now i want to render stage form in show page of project view. i tried but i am getting error. i want to use a link_to in show page of the project show to the form of the stage.

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :stages
  resources :projects
end
```

projects show.html.erb

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<p>
  <strong>Project name:</strong>
  <%= @project.project_name %>
</p>
<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_project_path(@project) %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', project_managers_path %>

<br>
<br>
<%= link_to "Add Stage", stage_form_path %>
```

project_controller.rb

```
  def index
    @projects = current_user.projects.all.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 15)
  end


  def show
    @stages = Stage.new
  end
```

each project has many stages relation in model.

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is:

```
  <%= link_to "Add Stage", form_stage_path %>
```

If confused about routes, run this command in console of your project before implementing them (linux):

```
rails routes (rake routes in older rails versions)

rails routes | grep stage

// the above command is specific to your case but grep searches for answers containing the string given to it (stage in this case).
```

Comment: this link_to give NameError

Comment: @Anuj Updated, there was a typo. Run this `rails routes | grep stage` first to see the path you need to give.

Comment: @Anuj is it form_stage_path or something else?

Comment: it's form_stage_path

Comment: Please paste your current error at the end of the question.